# There's some way to get content inside the printer object on vb6?

Tags: string, memory, printing, vb6, stream

i've a report api made by myself, this class is able to setup font and paper settings automatically, making a standard report layout.

so... i've tried to make pdf export function on my system, but if i use some third-party api i'll need to redraw my report and get a different report layout.

i think the printer object is able to join all the things we put in the print function  and print like only one string. Because this, i think the report inside the printer object is only a string, and if i could get that string i can make my pdf document with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB6 Printer object is just a set of interfaces.  These are used as a wrapper for the GDI calls used to accumulate drawing commands (including text drawing) page by page to make up a printer document.

Those commands are in an Enhanced Metafile format meant for print spooling.  Printer drivers then read, translate, and send (i.e. "play") these recorded commands to the actual printer once printing begins.

There is no giant string of text you can fish out of a Printer object.

[GDI Print API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[[MS-EMFSPOOL]: Enhanced Metafile Spool Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231034.aspx)